# Android application getting information from a website

Tags: android

I want to write an app get the information from posts (mostly about new classes) on my university website then make some annoucement once there is new class.

I've google and see RSS mostly, but the page I want to get data does not use RSS. I read something about website using service so we can read XML in the app, but I don't know if the page using service or not. Last resort is using host (somee for example) and js to get text from the page, then the app could read data from the host.

That's all I have right now, but it's still unclear for me. Any suggestion about what to read, what should I use?? Much appreciation

Comment: what you are trying to do is called `scraping`. libraries such as JSoup can help you extract information from an html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first thing you do should be to ask your uni if they provide any feed or webservice for these data that you could use.

If they don't, or don't answer at all, your last resort would be [scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). To do this, you can use an HTML parser, like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), and then go through the HTML data, getting information as you need.

To see if there are been changes, you would just have to cache your current processed information, probably in a database, and compare the new one to the one currently saved.